Hamiltonian for a permutation of particles
I want to know what Hamiltonian can be used to swap some particles around.
More specifically, let $A = (q_A, p_A)$, $B=(q_B, p_B)$, and $C=(q_C, p_C)$ be three classical particles, with positions $q_X$ and conjugate momenta $p_X$. In general, Hamilton's equations are $q_X = \{q_X, H\}$ and $p_X = \{p_X, H\}$ for each $X \in \{A, B, C\}$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian at $\{\cdot, \cdot\}$ is the Poisson Bracket. These equations admit unique solutions $q_X(t)$ and $p_X(t)$.
What I want to know is, is there an $H$ that gives me, for some specific time $t>0$, the following solutions:
$q_A(t) = q_C(0)$
$p_A(t) = p_C(0)$
$q_B(t) = q_A(0)$
$p_B(t) = p_A(0)$
$q_C(t) = q_B(0)$
$p_C(t) = p_B(0)$?
That is, what Hamiltonian, if any, eventually makes $B$ inherit $A$'s degrees of freedom; $C$ inherit $B$'s degrees of freedom; and $A$ inherit $C$'s degrees of freedom?
